# Solve answer optimization

Tags: equation-solving

I have an equation system (here is the simplified version for illustration)

```
    eq = Thread[
   Equal[{a[
        0]^2 (a[47]^2 (2 - 2 u[2] - 2 u[5] + 6 u[7] - 2 u[9] + 
            6 u[10] - 2 u[11] + 6 u[13] - 2 u[15] - 2 u[17]) + 
         a[49]^2 (2 - 2 u[2] - 2 u[5] + 6 u[7] - 2 u[9] + 6 u[10] - 
            2 u[11] + 6 u[13] - 2 u[15] - 2 u[17]) + 
         a[52]^2 (2 - 2 u[2] - 2 u[5] + 6 u[7] - 2 u[9] + 6 u[10] - 
            2 u[11] + 6 u[13] - 2 u[15] - 2 u[17])) + 
      a[47]^2 (a[
           49]^2 (2 + 2 u[1] - 2 u[2] + 2 u[3] - 6 u[4] + 6 u[5] - 
            6 u[6] - 2 u[7] + 2 u[8] - 2 u[9] + 6 u[10] - 2 u[11] + 
            2 u[12] - 2 u[13] - 6 u[14] + 6 u[15] + 2 u[16] - 
            2 u[17] + 2 u[18] - 6 u[19]) + 
         a[52]^2 (2 + 2 u[1] - 2 u[2] + 2 u[3] - 6 u[4] + 6 u[5] - 
            6 u[6] - 2 u[7] + 2 u[8] - 2 u[9] + 6 u[10] - 2 u[11] + 
            2 u[12] - 2 u[13] - 6 u[14] + 6 u[15] + 2 u[16] - 
            2 u[17] + 2 u[18] - 6 u[19])) + 
      a[0] a[47] a[49] a[
        52] (8 - 12 u[1] + 12 u[3] + 12 u[4] - 12 u[6] + 12 u[8] - 
         24 u[9] + 24 u[10] + 24 u[11] - 12 u[12] + 12 u[14] - 
         12 u[16] + 12 u[18] - 12 u[19]) + 
      a[49]^2 a[
        52]^2 (2 + 2 u[1] - 2 u[2] + 2 u[3] - 6 u[4] + 6 u[5] - 
         6 u[6] - 2 u[7] + 2 u[8] - 2 u[9] + 6 u[10] - 2 u[11] + 
         2 u[12] - 2 u[13] - 6 u[14] + 6 u[15] + 2 u[16] - 2 u[17] + 
         2 u[18] - 6 u[19]) + 
      a[47]^4 (-1 - u[1] + u[2] - u[3] - u[4] + u[5] - u[6] + u[7] - 
         u[8] + u[9] + u[10] + u[11] - u[12] + u[13] - u[14] + u[15] -
          u[16] + u[17] - u[18] - u[19]) + 
      a[49]^4 (-1 - u[1] + u[2] - u[3] - u[4] + u[5] - u[6] + u[7] - 
         u[8] + u[9] + u[10] + u[11] - u[12] + u[13] - u[14] + u[15] -
          u[16] + u[17] - u[18] - u[19]) + 
      a[52]^4 (-1 - u[1] + u[2] - u[3] - u[4] + u[5] - u[6] + u[7] - 
         u[8] + u[9] + u[10] + u[11] - u[12] + u[13] - u[14] + u[15] -
          u[16] + u[17] - u[18] - u[19]) + 
      a[0]^4 (-1 + u[1] + u[2] + u[3] + u[4] + u[5] + u[6] + u[7] + 
         u[8] + u[9] + u[10] + u[11] + u[12] + u[13] + u[14] + u[15] +
          u[16] + u[17] + u[18] + u[19]), 
     a[0]^2 a[49] a[
        52] (-8 u[1] + 4 u[2] + 8 u[3] + 12 u[4] - 4 u[6] - 4 u[7] - 
         4 u[9] + 8 u[11] - 4 u[12] - 8 u[13] + 4 u[15] + 4 u[16] + 
         4 u[18]) + 
      a[0]^3 a[
        47] (2 u[1] - 2 u[3] - 2 u[4] + 2 u[6] + 4 u[7] + 2 u[8] + 
         4 u[10] + 2 u[12] + 4 u[13] + 2 u[14] - 2 u[16] + 2 u[18] - 
         2 u[19]) + 
      a[49]^3 a[
        52] (4 u[4] - 4 u[5] + 4 u[6] - 4 u[10] + 4 u[14] - 4 u[15] + 
         4 u[19]) + 
      a[49] a[52]^3 (4 u[4] - 4 u[5] + 4 u[6] - 4 u[10] + 4 u[14] - 
         4 u[15] + 4 u[19]) + 
      a[47]^2 a[49] a[
        52] (4 u[1] - 4 u[2] + 4 u[3] - 4 u[7] + 4 u[8] - 4 u[9] + 
         8 u[11] - 8 u[12] + 8 u[13] + 12 u[14] - 12 u[15] - 
         8 u[16] + 8 u[17] - 8 u[18] + 12 u[19]) + 
      a[0] (a[47]^3 (-2 u[1] + 2 u[3] + 2 u[4] - 2 u[6] + 4 u[7] - 
            2 u[8] + 4 u[10] - 2 u[12] + 4 u[13] - 2 u[14] + 
            2 u[16] - 2 u[18] + 2 u[19]) + 
         a[47] (a[
              49]^2 (6 u[1] - 4 u[2] + 2 u[3] - 6 u[4] + 4 u[5] - 
               2 u[6] - 2 u[8] + 4 u[9] - 8 u[11] + 2 u[12] + 
               4 u[13] - 6 u[14] + 6 u[16] - 6 u[18] + 6 u[19]) + 
            a[52]^2 (6 u[1] - 4 u[2] + 2 u[3] - 6 u[4] + 4 u[5] - 
               2 u[6] - 2 u[8] + 4 u[9] - 8 u[11] + 2 u[12] + 4 u[13] 
               - 6 u[14] + 6 u[16] - 6 u[18] + 6 u[19]))), 
     a[0]^2 a[47] a[
        52] (-8 u[1] + 4 u[2] + 8 u[3] + 12 u[4] - 4 u[6] - 4 u[7] - 
         4 u[9] + 8 u[11] - 4 u[12] - 8 u[13] + 4 u[15] + 4 u[16] + 
         4 u[18]) + 
      a[0]^3 a[
        49] (2 u[1] - 2 u[3] - 2 u[4] + 2 u[6] + 4 u[7] + 2 u[8] + 
         4 u[10] + 2 u[12] + 4 u[13] + 2 u[14] - 2 u[16] + 2 u[18] - 
         2 u[19]) + 
      a[47]^3 a[
        52] (4 u[4] - 4 u[5] + 4 u[6] - 4 u[10] + 4 u[14] - 4 u[15] + 
         4 u[19]) + 
      a[47] a[52]^3 (4 u[4] - 4 u[5] + 4 u[6] - 4 u[10] + 4 u[14] - 
         4 u[15] + 4 u[19]) + 
      a[47] a[49]^2 a[
        52] (4 u[1] - 4 u[2] + 4 u[3] - 4 u[7] + 4 u[8] - 4 u[9] + 
         8 u[11] - 8 u[12] + 8 u[13] + 12 u[14] - 12 u[15] - 
         8 u[16] + 8 u[17] - 8 u[18] + 12 u[19]) + 
      a[0] (a[49]^3 (-2 u[1] + 2 u[3] + 2 u[4] - 2 u[6] + 4 u[7] - 
            2 u[8] + 4 u[10] - 2 u[12] + 4 u[13] - 2 u[14] + 
            2 u[16] - 2 u[18] + 2 u[19]) + 
         a[49] (a[
              47]^2 (6 u[1] - 4 u[2] + 2 u[3] - 6 u[4] + 4 u[5] - 
               2 u[6] - 2 u[8] + 4 u[9] - 8 u[11] + 2 u[12] + 
               4 u[13] - 6 u[14] + 6 u[16] - 6 u[18] + 6 u[19]) + 
            a[52]^2 (6 u[1] - 4 u[2] + 2 u[3] - 6 u[4] + 4 u[5] - 
               2 u[6] - 2 u[8] + 4 u[9] - 8 u[11] + 2 u[12] + 
               4 u[13] - 6 u[14] + 6 u[16] - 6 u[18] + 6 u[19]))), 
     a[0]^2 a[47] a[
        49] (-8 u[1] + 4 u[2] + 8 u[3] + 12 u[4] - 4 u[6] - 4 u[7] - 
         4 u[9] + 8 u[11] - 4 u[12] - 8 u[13] + 4 u[15] + 4 u[16] + 
         4 u[18]) + 
      a[0]^3 a[
        52] (2 u[1] - 2 u[3] - 2 u[4] + 2 u[6] + 4 u[7] + 2 u[8] + 
         4 u[10] + 2 u[12] + 4 u[13] + 2 u[14] - 2 u[16] + 2 u[18] - 
         2 u[19]) + 
      a[47]^3 a[
        49] (4 u[4] - 4 u[5] + 4 u[6] - 4 u[10] + 4 u[14] - 4 u[15] + 
         4 u[19]) + 
      a[0] (a[52]^3 (-2 u[1] + 2 u[3] + 2 u[4] - 2 u[6] + 4 u[7] - 
            2 u[8] + 4 u[10] - 2 u[12] + 4 u[13] - 2 u[14] + 
            2 u[16] - 2 u[18] + 2 u[19]) + 
         a[47]^2 a[
           52] (6 u[1] - 4 u[2] + 2 u[3] - 6 u[4] + 4 u[5] - 2 u[6] - 
            2 u[8] + 4 u[9] - 8 u[11] + 2 u[12] + 4 u[13] - 6 u[14] + 
            6 u[16] - 6 u[18] + 6 u[19]) + 
         a[49]^2 a[
           52] (6 u[1] - 4 u[2] + 2 u[3] - 6 u[4] + 4 u[5] - 2 u[6] - 
            2 u[8] + 4 u[9] - 8 u[11] + 2 u[12] + 4 u[13] - 6 u[14] + 
            6 u[16] - 6 u[18] + 6 u[19])) + 
      a[47] (a[
           49]^3 (4 u[4] - 4 u[5] + 4 u[6] - 4 u[10] + 4 u[14] - 
            4 u[15] + 4 u[19]) + 
         a[49] a[52]^2 (4 u[1] - 4 u[2] + 4 u[3] - 4 u[7] + 4 u[8] - 
            4 u[9] + 8 u[11] - 8 u[12] + 8 u[13] + 12 u[14] - 
            12 u[15] - 8 u[16] + 8 u[17] - 8 u[18] + 12 u[19]))}, 0]];
```

I want to solve them for any parameters a[_]. For this simple equation the answer is

```
SolveAlways[eq, {a[0], a[47], a[49], a[52]}]
```

Out[2]= {{u[2] -> -u[4] - u[6] - u[8] - 2 u[12] + 2 u[13] - 
 2 u[15] - u[16] + u[17] - 3 u[18] + 2 u[19],

u[5] -> u[4] + u[6] - u[10] + u[14] - u[15] + u[19],

u[7] -> -u[10] - u[13],

u[9] -> 2/3 + u[8] + u[10] + u[12] - u[13] + u[15] - u[17] + 
 2 u[18] - 2 u[19],

u[11] -> 1/3 + u[12] - u[13] - u[14] + u[15] + u[16] - u[17] + 
    u[18] - u[19],

u[1] -> -u[6] - u[8] - u[12] - u[14] - u[18],

u[3] -> -u[4] - u[16] - u[19]}}

So, I have 7 solution, from which only two of them have free constants 1/3 and 2/3. All other u[_], I can take zeros, so my simple answer is just u[9]->2/3 && u[11]->1/3

Unfortunately I need to solve much large system, which contains more that 7000 u[*], and SolveAlways[ ] simply cannot do that. Fortunately,  I can use linearity in u[*] and avoid SolveAlways[] completely using simple variable replacement

```
eqToUspace = (eq /. {y_Plus?(FreeQ[#, a[_]] &) :> uSpace[y]});
(toReplace = Union[Cases[eqToUspace, _uSpace, Infinity]]);
newvarsList = Table[ur[i], {i, Length[toReplace]}];
uReplRules = Thread[Rule[toReplace, newvarsList]];
```

Which yields the system

```
simpleEq = eqToUspace /. uReplRules
```

Out[2]= {a[0]^2 (a[47]^2 ur[1] + a[49]^2 ur[1] + a[52]^2 ur[1]) + 
   a[0] a[47] a[49] a[52] ur[3] + a[49]^2 a[52]^2 ur[4] + 
   a[47]^2 (a[49]^2 ur[4] + a[52]^2 ur[4]) + a[47]^4 ur[6] + 
   a[49]^4 ur[6] + a[52]^4 ur[6] + a[0]^4 ur[7] == 0, 
 a[0]^2 a[49] a[52] ur[2] + a[0]^3 a[47] ur[5] + a[49]^3 a[52] ur[9] +
    a[49] a[52]^3 ur[9] + 
   a[0] (a[47]^3 ur[8] + a[47] (a[49]^2 ur[10] + a[52]^2 ur[10])) + 
   a[47]^2 a[49] a[52] ur[11] == 0, 
 a[0]^2 a[47] a[52] ur[2] + a[0]^3 a[49] ur[5] + a[47]^3 a[52] ur[9] +
    a[47] a[52]^3 ur[9] + 
   a[0] (a[49]^3 ur[8] + a[49] (a[47]^2 ur[10] + a[52]^2 ur[10])) + 
   a[47] a[49]^2 a[52] ur[11] == 0, 
 a[0]^2 a[47] a[49] ur[2] + a[0]^3 a[52] ur[5] + a[47]^3 a[49] ur[9] +
    a[0] (a[52]^3 ur[8] + a[47]^2 a[52] ur[10] + 
      a[49]^2 a[52] ur[10]) + 
   a[47] (a[49]^3 ur[9] + a[49] a[52]^2 ur[11]) == 0}

Solution of which (can be tested by SolveAlways[] as well) is just zeroes:
{{ur[1] -> 0, ur[2] -> 0, ur[3] -> 0, ur[4] -> 0, ur[5] -> 0, 
  ur[6] -> 0, ur[7] -> 0, ur[8] -> 0, ur[9] -> 0, ur[10] -> 0, 
  ur[11] -> 0}}

After back substitution of old variables I can then solve the new system

```
unOptimized = 
 Solve[Thread[Equal[toReplace /. {uSpace -> Identity}, 0]], 
  Cases[toReplace, _u, Infinity]]
```

During evaluation of In[]:= Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables. >>

Out[167]= {{u[13] -> -u[7] - u[10], 
  u[17] -> 1 - u[2] - u[5] - u[9] - u[11] - u[15], 
  u[12] -> 1/3 - u[1] + u[3] + u[4] - u[6] - u[9] + u[10] + u[11], 
  u[18] -> 1/3 + u[1] - u[2] - u[3] - 2 u[4] - u[7] - u[10] - u[11] - 
    u[15] - u[16], 
  u[8] -> -(2/3) - u[1] + u[2] - u[3] + u[4] - u[5] + u[6] + u[7] + 
    u[9] - u[10], u[14] -> u[3] + u[5] - u[6] + u[10] + u[15] + u[16],
   u[19] -> -u[3] - u[4] - u[16]}}

It contains same number of solutions. The only problem is that it is unoptimal in the sense that instead of just 2 free constants I have 4. Of course this is related to which u[_] Solve decides to solve first.

My question is how to find optimal solution of the reformulated problem with smallest number of constant terms (i.e. which have no u[_]). I even cannot identify the type of problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a way, may be not to reduce calculation time, but to reduce memory usage with large systems.

First define all possible parameter combinations of the a[i] and then find the corresponding equations for the u[i]. In order to be valid for all a[i], these equations have all to equal zero.

```
paracomb = (Outer[
 Times, {a[0], a[47], a[49], a[52]}, {a[0], a[47], a[49], 
  a[52]}, {a[0], a[47], a[49], a[52]}, {a[0], a[47], a[49], 
  a[52]}] // Flatten // Union)

(*   {a[0]^4, a[0]^3 a[47], a[0]^2 a[47]^2, a[0] a[47]^3, a[47]^4, 
a[0]^3 a[49], a[0]^2 a[47] a[49], a[0] a[47]^2 a[49], a[47]^3 a[49], 
a[0]^2 a[49]^2, a[0] a[47] a[49]^2, a[47]^2 a[49]^2, a[0] a[49]^3, 
a[47] a[49]^3, a[49]^4, a[0]^3 a[52], a[0]^2 a[47] a[52], 
a[0] a[47]^2 a[52], a[47]^3 a[52], a[0]^2 a[49] a[52], 
a[0] a[47] a[49] a[52], a[47]^2 a[49] a[52], a[0] a[49]^2 a[52], 
a[47] a[49]^2 a[52], a[49]^3 a[52], a[0]^2 a[52]^2, 
a[0] a[47] a[52]^2, a[47]^2 a[52]^2, a[0] a[49] a[52]^2, 
a[47] a[49] a[52]^2, a[49]^2 a[52]^2, a[0] a[52]^3, a[47] a[52]^3, 
a[49] a[52]^3, a[52]^4}   *)

coe = Coefficient[eq[[All, 1]], #, 1] & /@ paracomb;

coeu = Union[Flatten[DeleteCases[#, 0] & /@ coe] // Simplify, 
          SameTest -> (#1 === -#2 || #1 === #2 &)]

(*   {-2 (-1 + u[2] + u[5] - 3 u[7] + u[9] - 3 u[10] + u[11] - 3 u[13] + 
u[15] + u[17]), -4 (2 u[1] - u[2] - 2 u[3] - 3 u[4] + u[6] + 
u[7] + u[9] - 2 u[11] + u[12] + 2 u[13] - u[15] - u[16] - u[18]), 
2 (1 + u[1] - u[2] + u[3] - 3 u[4] + 3 u[5] - 3 u[6] - u[7] + u[8] - 
u[9] + 3 u[10] - u[11] + u[12] - u[13] - 3 u[14] + 3 u[15] + 
u[16] - u[17] + u[18] - 3 u[19]), -1 - u[1] + u[2] - u[3] - u[4] +
u[5] - u[6] + u[7] - u[8] + u[9] + u[10] + u[11] - u[12] + u[13] - 
u[14] + u[15] - u[16] + u[17] - u[18] - 
u[19], -2 (u[1] - u[3] - u[4] + u[6] - 2 u[7] + u[8] - 2 u[10] + 
u[12] - 2 u[13] + u[14] - u[16] + u[18] - u[19]), 
2 (u[1] - u[3] - u[4] + u[6] + 2 u[7] + u[8] + 2 u[10] + u[12] + 
2 u[13] + u[14] - u[16] + u[18] - u[19]), 
4 (u[4] - u[5] + u[6] - u[10] + u[14] - u[15] + u[19]), -1 + u[1] + 
u[2] + u[3] + u[4] + u[5] + u[6] + u[7] + u[8] + u[9] + u[10] + 
u[11] + u[12] + u[13] + u[14] + u[15] + u[16] + u[17] + u[18] + 
u[19], -4 (-2 + 3 u[1] - 3 u[3] - 3 u[4] + 3 u[6] - 3 u[8] + 
6 u[9] - 6 u[10] - 6 u[11] + 3 u[12] - 3 u[14] + 3 u[16] - 
3 u[18] + 3 u[19]), 
2 (3 u[1] - 2 u[2] + u[3] - 3 u[4] + 2 u[5] - u[6] - u[8] + 2 u[9] - 
4 u[11] + u[12] + 2 u[13] - 3 u[14] + 3 u[16] - 3 u[18] + 
3 u[19]), 
4 (u[1] - u[2] + u[3] - u[7] + u[8] - u[9] + 2 u[11] - 2 u[12] + 
2 u[13] + 3 u[14] - 3 u[15] - 2 u[16] + 2 u[17] - 2 u[18] + 
3 u[19])}   *)
```

SolveAlways with a arbitrary variable r gives you the desired result

```
SolveAlways[Thread[coeu == 0], r] // Timing

(*    {0.015, {{u[2] -> -u[4] - u[6] - u[8] - 2 u[12] + 2 u[13] - 2 u[15] - 
 u[16] + u[17] - 3 u[18] + 2 u[19], 
 u[5] -> u[4] + u[6] - u[10] + u[14] - u[15] + u[19], 
 u[7] -> -u[10] - u[13], 
 u[9] -> 2/3 + u[8] + u[10] + u[12] - u[13] + u[15] - u[17] + 
 2 u[18] - 2 u[19], 
 u[11] -> 
 1/3 + u[12] - u[13] - u[14] + u[15] + u[16] - u[17] + u[18] - 
 u[19], u[1] -> -u[6] - u[8] - u[12] - u[14] - u[18], 
 u[3] -> -u[4] - u[16] - u[19]}}}    *)
```

Despite expectation Solve doesn't give the minimal solution

```
Solve[Thread[coeu == 0], Array[u, 19]] // Timing

(*    {0., {{u[10] -> -(2/3) - u[1] + u[2] - u[3] + u[4] - u[5] + u[6] + 
 u[7] - u[8] + u[9], 
 u[12] -> -(1/3) - 2 u[1] + u[2] + 2 u[4] - u[5] + u[7] - u[8] + 
 u[11], u[13] -> 
 2/3 + u[1] - u[2] + u[3] - u[4] + u[5] - u[6] - 2 u[7] + u[8] - 
 u[9], u[16] -> 
 2/3 + u[1] - u[2] - u[4] - u[7] + u[8] - u[9] + u[14] - u[15], 
 u[17] -> 1 - u[2] - u[5] - u[9] - u[11] - u[15], 
 u[18] -> 
 1/3 + u[1] - u[2] - 2 u[4] + u[5] - u[6] - u[7] - u[11] - u[14], 
 u[19] -> -(2/3) - u[1] + u[2] - u[3] + u[7] - u[8] + u[9] - u[14] +
  u[15]}}}    *)
```

But Solve with reduced variable set does like SolveAlways.

```
Solve[Thread[coeu == 0], Array[u, 12]] // Timing
```

Comment: Your get the solution of SolveAlways, because you dropped some of variables, which, fortunately, were not important. Once we know the answer, we can do that. Unfortunately, if, for example you will drop u[11] or u[9] you will never get same solution. If I want to apply this trick to  the real problem I want to solve  I need to know what 4 (I suspect) variables of total 7500 are important.   Thanks for considering this problem

Comment: No @user18792,  you are not true. With `SolveAlways[Thread[coeu == 0], r] // Timing`, I didn't drop any variable. You get the same with `SolveAlways[Thread[coeu == 0], {a[0], a[47], a[49], a[52]}] // Timing` , Try it for your large system. The last line `Solve[Thread[coeu == 0], Array[u, 12]] // Timing`is only for showing you Solve is not optimal for that case.

Comment: My comment was just about last Solve command with dropped vars. Your idea about taking only independent terms is sound and really good. And I will try it.

Comment: I just see, Solve without definition of variables also does the desired job `Solve[Thread[coeu == 0]] // Timing`

Comment: Very interesting. SolveAlways still running on the true problem (not an easy task for equations with 15*10^6 LeafCount), however memory consumption now is at least twise less that  in the originally formulated problem. I want to let it finish before accepting the answer. I will let you know.

Comment: I aborted the calculation of SolveAlways of my larger system after two days of run. There were still a lot of memory available, so I think it was a progress and I accept your answer despite negative result. It was a difficult problem and the main reason why I aborted, that the https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164581/solve-answer-rewrite/164595?noredirect=1#comment435878_164595 suggestion with FindMinimum was able to find the solution. Thank you again