# Solve answer rewrite

Tags: equation-solving

It is simpler reformulation of the former [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164494/solve-answer-optimization).

I have simple system of equations which at the same time a solutions:

```
eq = {u[13] == -u[7] - u[10], 
  u[17] == 1 - u[2] - u[5] - u[9] - u[11] - u[15], 
  u[12] == 1/3 - u[1] + u[3] + u[4] - u[6] - u[9] + u[10] + u[11], 
  u[18] == 1/3 + u[1] - u[2] - u[3] - 2 u[4] - u[7] - u[10] - u[11] - 
    u[15] - u[16], 
  u[8] == -(2/3) - u[1] + u[2] - u[3] + u[4] - u[5] + u[6] + u[7] + 
    u[9] - u[10], u[14] == u[3] + u[5] - u[6] + u[10] + u[15] + u[16],
   u[19] == -u[3] - u[4] - u[16]}
```

These solution has 4 constant terms (or stated as a problem for LinearSolve[ ] 4 nonzero constants): 1,1/3,1/3 and -2/3 (nonhomogeneaus part). I know it can be rewritten as a solution with just 2 nonzero constants when solved for different u[_]:

```
In[2]:= Solve[eq, {u[9], u[11], u[1], u[2], u[5], u[7], u[3]}]
```

Out[2]= {{u[9] -> 
   2/3 + u[8] + u[10] + u[12] - u[13] + u[15] - u[17] + 2 u[18] - 
    2 u[19], 
  u[11] -> 1/3 + u[12] - u[13] - u[14] + u[15] + u[16] - u[17] + 
    u[18] - u[19], u[1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164494/solve-answer-optimization) -> -u[6] - u[8] - u[12] - u[14] - u[18], 
  u[2] -> -u[4] - u[6] - u[8] - 2 u[12] + 2 u[13] - 2 u[15] - u[16] + 
    u[17] - 3 u[18] + 2 u[19], 
  u[5] -> u[4] + u[6] - u[10] + u[14] - u[15] + u[19], 
  u[7] -> -u[10] - u[13], u[3] -> -u[4] - u[16] - u[19]}}

Indeed, now the nonhomogeneus terms are just 2/3 and 1/3. How to find variables  i. e., for example, {u[9], u[11], u[1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164494/solve-answer-optimization), u[2], u[5], u[7], u[3]} with minimal number of constants terms?

These equations occur when trying to construct (of 19 available formulas) the simplest possible expression. Zeroes means that the terms can be omitted. Nonzero coefficients are weights of the terms which, when added, match the sought expression. So, it is an optimal rewrite problem. What linear algebra operation can describe it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This involves what is known as l_0 minimization, and that is in general a "hard" problem. I can show a common surrogate method which somethis works (not quite in this case though). It is to instead do an l_1 optimization, which is handled by standard linear programming.

The idea:
(0) Extract a matrix and right hand side vector from the equations.
(1) Get a specific solution.
(2) Get null vectors for the matrix.
(3) Form a general solution as specific solution plus arbitrary combination of nulls (use a new variable for each null vector).
(4) The linear programming problem is to minimize the sum of absolute values of the coordinates of the general solution. This is the surrogate for minimizing the number of nonzero components.

Here is step (0) (should have been (1) but I'm too lazy to renumber).

```
eq = {u[13] == -u[7] - u[10], 
   u[17] == 1 - u[2] - u[5] - u[9] - u[11] - u[15], 
   u[12] == 1/3 - u[1] + u[3] + u[4] - u[6] - u[9] + u[10] + u[11], 
   u[18] == 
    1/3 + u[1] - u[2] - u[3] - 2 u[4] - u[7] - u[10] - u[11] - u[15] -
      u[16], u[8] == -(2/3) - u[1] + u[2] - u[3] + u[4] - u[5] + 
     u[6] + u[7] + u[9] - u[10], 
   u[14] == u[3] + u[5] - u[6] + u[10] + u[15] + u[16], 
   u[19] == -u[3] - u[4] - u[16]};
linpolys = Apply[Subtract, eq, {1}];
vars = Variables[linpolys];
{rhs, mat} = Normal[CoefficientArrays[linpolys, vars]]

(* Out[4324]= {{0, -1, -(1/3), -(1/3), 2/3, 0, 
  0}, {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
   1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 
   0, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {-1, 1, 
   1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, -1, 1, -1, 
   1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 
   1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}}} *)
```

Steps (1-3):

```
onesoln = LinearSolve[mat, rhs];
nulls = NullSpace[mat];
gensolnvars = Array[a, Length[nulls]];
gensoln = onesoln + gensolnvars.nulls;
```

[Also note: per comment/correction by original poster, this should have begun with `onesoln = LinearSolve[mat, -rhs];`. I'm leaving the mistake intact because the weaker result helps to motivate the second approach at bottom.]

Step (4) is done by adding yet more variables, one per general solution coordinate, and adding constraints that each is greater-equal to both the corresponding coordinate and its negative. Then minimize the sum of these new variables.

```
l1normvars = Array[c, Length[gensoln]];
constraints = 
  Join[Thread[l1normvars >= gensoln], 
   Thread[l1normvars >= -gensoln]];
{min, vals} = 
 Minimize[{Total[l1normvars], constraints}, 
  Join[gensolnvars, l1normvars]]

(* Out[4327]= {1, {a[1] -> 0, a[2] -> 0, a[3] -> -(1/3), a[4] -> 0, 
  a[5] -> 0, a[6] -> 0, a[7] -> 0, a[8] -> 0, a[9] -> 0, 
  a[10] -> -(1/3), a[11] -> 0, a[12] -> 0, c[1] -> 0, c[2] -> 1/3, 
  c[3] -> 0, c[4] -> 0, c[5] -> 0, c[6] -> 0, c[7] -> 0, c[8] -> 0, 
  c[9] -> 1/3, c[10] -> 0, c[11] -> 0, c[12] -> 0, c[13] -> 0, 
  c[14] -> 0, c[15] -> 0, c[16] -> 0, c[17] -> 1/3, c[18] -> 0, 
  c[19] -> 0}} *)
```

The result is an improvement over the original in that only three coordinates are nonzero.

```
onesoln + (gensolnvars /. vals).nulls

(* Out[4328]= {0, -(1/3), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -(1/
  3), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -(1/3), 0, 0} *)
```

Still not optimal in the sense originally requested. But it's a start I guess.

One can do better using integer linear programming. One method, not exactly guaranteed but works in this case, is to insist that all the nonzero components be integer valued. `NMinimize` does not at this time handle a mix of integer and real-valued variables so instead we will use `FindMinimum` (which uses the mixed integer programming capabilities of the `COIN-CBC` library).

```
{min, vals} = 
 FindMinimum[{Total[l1normvars], constraints, 
   Element[l1normvars, Integers]}, Join[gensolnvars, l1normvars]]

(* Out[4350]= {2., {a[1] -> 0., a[2] -> 0., a[3] -> 0., a[4] -> 0., 
  a[5] -> 0., a[6] -> 0., a[7] -> 0., a[8] -> 0., a[9] -> 0., 
  a[10] -> -0.666666666667, a[11] -> 0., a[12] -> 0., c[1] -> 0, 
  c[2] -> 0, c[3] -> 0, c[4] -> 0, c[5] -> 0, c[6] -> 0, c[7] -> 0, 
  c[8] -> 0, c[9] -> 1, c[10] -> 0, c[11] -> 1, c[12] -> 0, 
  c[13] -> 0, c[14] -> 0, c[15] -> 0, c[16] -> 0, c[17] -> 0, 
  c[18] -> 0, c[19] -> 0}} *)
```

Let's see how we fared.

```
onesoln + (gensolnvars /. vals).nulls

(* Out[4348]= {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., -0.666666666667, 0., \
-0.333333333333, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.} *)
```

So there we are, only two nonzero coordinates remaining.

Comment: Thank you very much, Daniel. Quietly I hoped that your will notice the question, which is an important step of one of scientific problem I now trying to attack. In fact the above simple example was generated when solving inverse problem in Clifford algebra for dim=6 case https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.05204  ... and now we try to do the same thing for dim=7 case. I will try your method for this new problem, which now consist of 54 similar linear equations with approx 7500 variables.

Comment: Just to note that correcting a little sign typo onesoln = LinearSolve[mat, rhs]; -> onesoln = LinearSolve[mat, -rhs] the optimal solution is obtained already with Minimize[].

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I'll leave the error but add a remark about it (the weaker result motivates the more hard-core method that follows).

Comment: Just to inform that the FindMinimum was able to find the solution of my larger system after 4 hours of run. Because of this, I aborted Minimize after two days of run. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm glad this worked for the larger problem. I was not at all sure it would scale quite that far.

Answer (score 2):

Here a third way. Repeatedly set all free variables to zero to significantly reduce the equation set.

You have 7 equations and 19 unknowns.
First regard only the equations with no constant term and set all variables (here 9 variables) to zero.

```
(eq2 = eq[[All, 1]] - eq[[All, 2]]) // TableForm

uzero = Cases[Flatten[List @@ # & /@ Drop[eq2, {2, 5}]], u[_]]

(*    {u[7], u[10], u[13], u[6], u[14], u[3], u[4], u[16], u[19]}    *)
```

You get a reduced equation set, where you too set those variables from non-constant term equations to zero

```
eq3 = DeleteCases[eq2 /. Thread[uzero -> 0], 0]

(*    {-1 + u[2] + u[5] + u[9] + u[11] + u[15] + u[17], -(1/3) + u[1] + 
       u[9] - u[11] + u[12], -(1/3) - u[1] + u[2] + u[11] + u[15] + u[18], 
       2/3 + u[1] - u[2] + u[5] + u[8] - u[9], -u[5] - u[15]}    *)

eq4 = DeleteCases[(eq3 /. {u[5] -> 0, u[15] -> 0}), 0]

(*    u[11] == 1/3 + u[12] - u[17] + u[18] && 
      u[8] == -(2/3) + u[9] - u[12] + u[17] - 2 u[18] && 
      u[2] == 2/3 - u[9] - u[12] - u[18] && 
      u[1] == 2/3 - u[9] - u[17] + u[18]    *)
```

If nessecary, do this further times. Now there remain 4 equations with 8 unknowns. 
In order to get a minimal solution, set those variables, that appear only one time, to zero.

```
DeleteCases[List @@ # & /@ eq4 // Flatten // Sort, _?NumericQ]

(*   {-u[1], u[1], u[1], -u[2], u[2], u[2], u[8], -u[9], u[9], 
       u[9], -u[11], u[11], u[11], u[12], u[17], u[18]}    *)

eq5 = Thread[(eq4 /. {u[8] -> 0, u[12] -> 0, u[17] -> 0, 
   u[18] -> 0}) == 0] // Simplify
```

In other words: Ramain the x variables, that appear most times in the remaining x equations and set the others to zero.

Now Reduce or Solve

```
eq5 // Reduce

(*    u[11] == 1/3 && u[9] == 2/3 && u[2] == 0 && u[1] == 0    *)
```

Comment: I already tried to reduce number of not relevant equations, however, not so drastically. I will definitely try this and report results later.

Answer (score 1):

What about a way that is quite brute force, but very fast.

First FindMinimum with all starting values at zero.

```
Array[u, 19] /. Last@FindMinimum[Flatten[{1, eq}], 
                Table[{u[i], 0}, {i, 19}]] // Chop

(*   {0, 0, 0, 0.333333, 0.333333, 0, 0, 0, 0.666667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \
      -0.333333, 0, 0, 0}    *)
```

Now set succesivly all u[i], that are not zero, to zero and in a few cases get the minimal solution very fast.

```
Array[u, 19] /. Last@FindMinimum[Flatten[{1, eq, u[4] == 0}], 
 Table[{u[i], 0}, {i, 19}]] // Chop // Timing

(*   {2.1684*10^-19, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.666667, 0, 0.333333, 0, 0, 
                      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}    *)

Array[u, 19] /. Last@FindMinimum[Flatten[{1, eq, u[5] == 0}], 
 Table[{u[i], 0}, {i, 19}]] // Chop // Timing

(*   {2.1684*10^-19, {0, 0, 0, 0.333333, 0, -0.333333, 0, 0.333333, 1., 0, 
                      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.333333, 0, 0, 0}}   *)

Array[u, 19] /. Last@FindMinimum[Flatten[{1, eq, u[9] == 0}], 
 Table[{u[i], 0}, {i, 19}]] // Chop // Timing

(*   {1.35525*10^-17, {0.5, 1., 0, -0.166667, 0, 0, 0.166667, 0, 
                       0, -0.166667, 0, -0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.166667, 0, 0, 0}}   *)

 Array[u, 19] /. Last@FindMinimum[Flatten[{1, eq, u[16] == 0}], 
 Table[{u[i], 0}, {i, 19}]] // Chop // Timing

(*   {1.35525*10^-17, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.666667, 0, 0.333333, 0, 0,
                       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}    *)
```

Comment: Under the hood this will use linear programming. It does not come with guarantees, but it does seem like a reasonable heuristic.

Comment: I tested this with my larger system, unfortunately it only managed to  reduce the number of terms by 1.  Despite additional equations new nonzero coefficients reappear. Still struggling with the problem, because FindMinimum was able to find the solution only in one particular case. It would also be interesting to somehow monitor the progress of FindMinimum, however I cannot think how. (Seems that EvaluationMonitor cannot print anything in this case while the search is not finished).